# React & MobX: доступ к дочерним компонентам из родителя для получения данных

Tags: reactjs, react-native, компоненты, mobx, mobx-react-lite

Подскажите как корректнее реализовать следующую идею:

У меня есть мои компоненты, написанные на React, отвечающие за получение от пользователя разнообразных данных (подготовленные списки и т.д.) типа

```
<MyElement_Users>
<MyElement_Countries>
```

и т.д.

Элементы естественно полностью самостоятельные, т.е. сбор данных, предварительная обработка и отрисовка происходит внутри компонента без взаимодействия с другими компонентами.

Из данных компонент можно собирать блоки типа за который отвечает отдельный компонент `MyFilters` типа

```
<MyFilters title = "Информация #1">
    <MyElement_Users>
    <MyElement_Countries>
    <MyElement_Products>
    <MyElement_Apply>
</MyFilters>
```

или

```
<MyFilters title = "Информация #2">
    <MyElement_Countries>
    <MyElement_Apply>
</MyFilters>
```

Т.е. в данном построении  знает о своих дочерних компонентах и строит их

```
<Container>
    {props.children}
</Container>
```

А дочерние элементы не знают о своем родители и о своих соседях.

Я хочу сделать следующее:

Чтобы по нажатию кнопки `<MyElement_Apply`> собирались данные от дочерних элементов `<MyFilters>` для последующей работы с ними.

Вся логика работы с собранными данными также сидит в `<MyFilters>`, поэтому:

- от элемента `MyElement_Apply` требуется, чтобы он как-то проинформировал элемент `<MyFilters>`, что необходим сбор и анализ данных (по сути вызвать функцию `MyFilters.my_analyze()`
- от остальных дочерних элементов требуется как-то передать свои данные родителю `<MyFilters>`

При этом очень не хочется при построении блоков передавать явно какие-то данные дочерним элементам, типа

```
<MyFilters title = "Информация #2">
    <MyElement_Countries container = {this.container}>
    <MyElement_Apply parent = {this}>
</MyFilters>
```

Хотелось бы обойтись минимализмом в этом вопросе (т.е. внутри логика может быть сложной, но снаружи такое простое использование, чтобы новые блоки можно было бы собирать обычной копи-пастой)

Подскажите как более корректно реализовать такой подход?

Если такое невозможно, то подумалось над следующим (хотелось бы реализовать через MobX) - стоит ли тогда подходить так:

1. `<MyFilters>` создаёт/содержит внутри себя контейнер
2. контейнер (в виде ссылки или еще какого механизма) передаётся явно (к сожалению) всем дочерним компонентам
3. компонент `<MyElement_Apply>` устанавливает в контейнере флаг `isApplied = true`
4. MobX отслеживает изменение данного поля и дёргает соответствующий метод `MyFilters.my_analyze()`

Подскажите корректен ли такой подход и как его лучше реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

С mobx я пока не пробовал.

Идея такая, что отделить разделяемый стейт от компонентов.

Если есть стейт, который меняет компонент Users и смотрит компонент Apply, то этот стейт объявляется явным образом *рядом* с ними, и передается им через пропы.

Внутри компонент может реагировать на переданный стейт: `useEffect(()=>setOutput(calc(input)),[input])`

Comment: т.е. всё таки потребутся явное задание?


Вообще был в голове еще один вариант, но я не знаю реализуется ли он силами React - при создании (отрисовке) дочерних элементов им явно задается  ссылка на контейнер, который они заполняют своими данными

Comment: так я об этом и написал

Comment: явное не требуется, можно и через контекст делать; вопрос, что кода сэкономим вроде не много, а вспоминать потом, как работает, дольше